# What should I do with a answer that's a comment if the users under 50 reputation

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was in the middle of reviewing [This is the SO post and I realized I didn't know if it was ok to use an answer as a comment if the user doesn't have communication privileges.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821623/jenkins-nunit-test-reports-are-not-rendering-in-emails)

Should I say no action needed or flag this post?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flag the post as "Not an Answer." Not having a privilege is not a valid excuse for circumventing site restrictions.

Comment: I bet you wish you still had insta-delete privileges, right?

Comment: @bluefeet That and access to the TL are the two things I miss the most.

Comment: @bluefeet: Hey, remember when [REDACTED] [REDACTED] the [REDACTED] [REDACTED] [REDACTED] but [REDACTED] [REDACTED] and [REDACTED]? Ah, those were [REDACTED] times.

Answer (score 4):

It should be deleted.

Answers shouldn't be used for comments.

We restrict the ability to comment to users over 50 rep for a reason. If you see answers that are really comments, flag as VLQ or vote to delete.

Comment: Flagging as NAA is more logical, and allows to also flag if the non-answer happens to have positive score. Voting to delete isn't a good option: it does not subject the post to further review by others (not to mention the 20K and negative score requirements). Together with flagging, maybe -- but usually it's a delete vote wasted, as the majority of cases in LQRQ are handled via Recommend Deletion route, without acquiring 3 delete votes.

Comment: @Idisagree: Wonderful nick.